# Open jquery dialog in parent iframe within second iframe within second dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, dialog

I tried to search in StackOverflow and I found similar solutions for my problem but I just can't make this work.

**HTML EXAMPLE:**

```
<iframe id="iframeA">
   <!-- Here i open a dialog "**divOffirstDialog**"-->
    <div id="divOffirstDialog">
      <iframe id="iframeB">
        ...(contents)...
           <button onclick="openSecondDialog('divOfsecondDialog')">
           <div id="divOfsecondDialog"></div>
      </iframe>
    </div>
</iframe>
```

**WORKFLOW:**

Open dialog **divOffirstDialog** in **iframeA** -> inside dialog open **divOfsecondDialog** to open the second dialog.

**PROBLEM:**

The second dialog opens inside the first one.

**QUESTION:**

How can i open the second dialog above/outside the first dialog. How can i open ouside **iframeB** in **iframeA**?

**NOTE:**

Both iframes are in same domain.